# How to build same project with two different java version and target into two seperate folder?

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci

I have a maven project .whenever it pushes into gitlap, it will be deployed with single java version using CI option. I need to build with two different java version on same project when commit the project. So, How to create pom file to achive this using maven?

Comment: Why do you need to build with two different java versions? Which versions?

Comment: Because of clients who is not ready to change to latest java .thats why i need two build .I need for java 8 and java 12

Comment: Just build with Java 8 and it can simply run on Java 12...?

Comment: you are correct thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got englightened by @khmarbaise comment and made me think this way as follows,

I have a java project which compile with java8 and can run on higher version than this, in my case java 12. So, creating two build with two different java version on same project is not necessory as i know.

In another case, even if i use "java12 feauture" on project,i could not compile with java8, So, i have to create two different project for java8(for clients needs) and java12. So,There is no complication in this scenerio to achieve my needs.

if any scenerio i miss here, please comment!!!

Comment: With Java 9 they introduced the multirelease jar and it is supported by Maven, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/multirelease.html . However, think twice before using it, because it is a lot harder to maintain.

Comment: The question is: What feature of Java 12 do you really need? And of course follow the guidelines of Robert...